# error seqtreedisplay because of GraphViz

Tags: r, traminer

I'm trying to reproduce the example in the tutorial (pag 7)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WeightedCluster/vignettes/WeightedCluster.pdf

Before running

```
R> seqtreedisplay(wardTree, type="d", border=NA, showdepth=TRUE)
```

I need to install GraphViz, but it is not in CRAN anymore so I installed it from bioconductor and works fine

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rgraphviz")
```

The library I got installed is 
library(Rgraphviz)
and it is correctly loaded but when running 
R> seqtreedisplay(wardTree, type="d", border=NA, showdepth=TRUE)

I get the error

```
Error in disstreedisplayInternal(tree = tree, filename = filename, tmpdisstree = tmpdisstree,  : 
   [!] GraphViz was not found. If you haven't, please install GraphViz to use this function: see http://www.graphviz.org
 [!] If GraphViz is installed on your computer, you need to specify the GraphViz installation directory using the argument gvpath='installdir'
 [!] You can also add this directory to the PATH environment variable
 [!] GraphViz installation directory usually looks like 'C:\Program Files\GraphViz'
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c " "\bin\dot.exe"  -Tpng -otmpseqtree4585dc9564c.png tmpseqtree4585dc9564c.dot "' had status 1
```

Is that one the library that should be installed and loaded?
I'm confused because of the change of names in the library before was GraphViz now it seems to be Rgraphviz

Answer (score 1):

`TraMineR` and its `seqtreedisplay` function do not use the `Rgraphviz` package.

To use `seqtreedisplay`, you need to install (outside of `R`) the independent **GraphViz** program that you can download from http://www.graphviz.org/.

You may have to add the path to that program in your path.

Comment: Is impossible to make seqtreedisplay function with Rgraphviz? I work in a computing environment where the administrator will not install the standalone Graphviz but will allow Rgraphviz.

Comment: Unfortunately, TraMineR does currently not offer that possibility.

Comment: Thanks. Knowing this will probably help me to convince my admin to install the standalone Graphviz.